# Como cadastrar uma matriz de dados no Django

Tags: ajax, python, django

Tenho uma matriz de dados na minha session storage relacionada a produtos de uma loja, e gostaria de cadastrar uma venda assim que o usuário cadastrar todos os seus produtos e clicar em finalizar venda.

Essa matriz de produtos vai ganhando uma linha a cada novo produto cadastro na minha venda.

Como faço pra pegar essa session storage e gravar no meu banco de dados?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como está essa listagem de produtos?
Já que é uma lista de dados, você deve utilizar o bulk_create para isso:

```
#se sua listagem for um dict

produtos = request.session['produtos']
lista = []
for produto in produtos:
     lista.append(Produto(nome=produto['nome'], valor=produto['valor']))

Produto.objects.bulk_create(lista)
```

Isto fará otimizará o tempo de criação. Caso sejam 100 produtos a serem criados, ele monta a lista e cria tudo de uma só vez, em vez de criar um a um.

Comment: Legal! Esta listagem é uma matriz, existe um formulário que vou salvando os produtos nela, pensei que teria que usar AJAX para buscar a session storage.

Comment: A session que me referi acima, é a do próprio django. Você tem que ver como está armazenando seus produtos e enviar isso na requisição para salvar. Não necessariamente você vai pegar os produtos dessa maneira, mas para salvar, é interessante que utilize o bulk_create

Comment: Ah sim, estou com dificuldades em levar essa matriz para o Django, acho que vou ter que usar essa própria sessão que ele cria e não a session storage do navegador. Tu me recomenda algo pra fazer isso?

Comment: Você pode fazer a adição desse produto na lista por ajax e na hora do post, pegar essa listagem completa ou criar um evento no js para o submit do seu form pegar e enviar esses dados.

Comment: Ok, entedi! O `bulk_create` não vai ter problemas com a chave estrangeira?

Comment: Não, ele serve para otimizar esse processo de criação de um mesmo tipo de objeto. Caso você possua uma ForeignKey em seu model, basta você montar a sua lista com ela: lista.append(Produto(nome=produto['nome'], valor=produto['valor'], user=request.user))

Comment: Ok, obrigado! Vou fazer aqui e confirmo a sua resposta :D

Comment: Veja: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/querysets/#bulk-create

Comment: Só mais uma dúvida, eu crio meu formulário de produto pela view ou com HTML puro?

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30749/discussion-between-puam-dias-and-rodrigo-boniatti).